# Counting the total of same running processes in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process

I'm looking for a way to detect the # of running processes that has same process name.

In example, I ran notepad three times.

notepad.exe
notepad.exe
notepad.exe

So it will return 3.

I currently have these code to detect a running process, but not counting its running process quantity.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>

bool IsProcessRunning(const char *ProcessName);

int main()
{
  char *notepadRunning = (IsProcessRunning("notepad.exe")) ? "Yes" : "No";
  std::cout << "Is Notepad running? " << notepadRunning;
  return 0;
}

bool IsProcessRunning(const char *ProcessName)
{
   PROCESSENTRY32 pe32 = { sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32) };
   HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

   if(Process32First(hSnapshot, &pe32))
   {
      do
      {
         if(_tcsicmp(pe32.szExeFile, ProcessName) == 0)
         {
            CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
            return true;
         }
      } while(Process32Next(hSnapshot, &pe32));
   }

   CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
   return false;
}
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the correct API, namely [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682489(VS.85).aspx), [Process32First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684834(VS.85).aspx) and [Process32Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684836(VS.85).aspx).  And as you are doing, you should be using the szExeFile member from the struct [PROCESSENTRY32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684839(VS.85).aspx).

You are returning from your function when you find a match currently though. Instead you should be incrementing a counter and NOT returning.  And return an int with the process count instead of a bool.  Also be sure not to do CloseHandle(hSnapshot); until the end of the function after you have the count.

Also make sure to first acquire the privilege `SeDebugPrivilege` before enumerating, that way you will get all processes across all sessions and users.

To acquire the privilege so you get all sessions:

```
acquirePrivilegeByName(SE_DEBUG_NAME);// SeDebugPrivilege
```

Where acquirePrivilegeByName is defined as:

```
BOOL acquirePrivilegeByName(
                            const TCHAR     *szPrivilegeName)
{
    HANDLE          htoken;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES    tkp;
    DWORD           dwerr;

    //---------------- adjust process token privileges to grant privilege
    if (szPrivilegeName == NULL)
    {
        SetLastError(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, szPrivilegeName, &(tkp.Privileges[0].Luid)))
        return FALSE;

    tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &htoken))
        return FALSE;

    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(htoken, FALSE, &tkp, 0, NULL, NULL) ||
        GetLastError() != ERROR_SUCCESS)    // may equal ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED
    {
        dwerr = GetLastError();
        CloseHandle(htoken);
        SetLastError(dwerr);
        return FALSE;
    }

    CloseHandle(htoken);
    SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS);

    return TRUE;
} //acquirePrivilegeByName()
```

Comment: Thanks! it's as simple as removing the CloseHandle!

Answer (score 0):

You may have problems with access rights. In particular on Vista I don't think you can enumerate all processes unless you run with elevated privileges.

You could also try to use the [EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629(VS.85).aspx) API. There is a [complete example on how to enumerate all processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682623(VS.85).aspx).