# How to find processes by ProcessID?

Tags: c, windows

Is there a way to find processes by a PID? So let's say, i create a process, let's say cmd.exe with `CreateProcess`. From this cmd i open a notepad, and a paint. Is it possible to find those processes somehow? What i need is the PID from those processes.

Could someone please help me. It would be really important to me.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531837/how-can-i-get-the-pid-of-the-parent-process-of-my-application/2533287#2533287

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, but this is in C#, but i need it in C or C++.

Comment: Can you tell us what you want to do with the PID of those grandchild processes?

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example in the msdn microsoft windows api. check out this next link.

[Enumerating All Processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682623(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, for your help, but that's not quite what i want. If i start a process, like cmd, and from this cmd, i start other processes, then i want the pid's of these other processes.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create your own shell of some kind. The CreateProcess call you mentioned contains a pointer to a PROCESS_INFORMATION structure of the newly created process, containing the PID. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the PID of the cmd, then I think you can use logic similar to the logic listed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185254/how-can-a-win32-process-get-the-pid-of-its-parent) to accomplish the task.