# Getting Parent of nested applications

Tags: c#, process

**I don't believe this should be marked as a duplicate**

Here is my scenario. I need to check if an application is running in a RemoteApp session.
RemoteApp launches an application menu window which then launches other applications so the chain should be as follows.

```
rdpinit.exe > appmenu.exe > myapp.exe
```

So I need to accomplish the following. Check the parent process of myapp.exe which should return appmenu.exe, I then need to know what launched appmenu.exe which should return rdpinit.

btw rdpinit.exe is RemoteApp

I'm doing the following now but can't get to the point where it's rdpinit

```
        public static string IsRemoteApp()
    {
        Process currentProc = ParentProcessUtilities.GetParentProcess();
        do
        {
            currentProc = GetParentProcess(currentProc.Id);
            if (currentProc != null)
            {
                if (currentProc.ProcessName.Equals("rdpinit"))
                {
                    //return true;
                }
            }
        }
        while (currentProc != null);
        //return false;
        return currentProc.ProcessName;
    }

    private static Process GetParentProcess(int procId)
    {
        try
        {
            string query = string.Format("SELECT ParentProcessId FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = {0}", procId);
            ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", query);
            ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator results = search.Get().GetEnumerator();
            if (!results.MoveNext())
            {
                return null;
            }

            ManagementBaseObject queryObj = results.Current;
            uint parentID = (uint)queryObj["ParentProcessId"];
            return Process.GetProcessById((int)parentID);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I have tried just a while loop also

```
 Process currentProc = ParentProcessUtilities.GetParentProcess();

            while (GetParentProcess(currentProc.Id) != null)
            {
                currentProc = GetParentProcess(currentProc.Id);
            }

            return currentProc.ProcessName;
```

I can only ever get appmenu.exe

Also what I was thinking which I don't believe this can always be assumed but it might is.
Get my session id of myapp, grab process[] of rpdinit. If rdpinit equals the same session id then I can assume it was launched by RemoteApp.

Seems like there can be a scenario where this will be true when the app wasn't actually launched by RemoteApp

Comment: sorry, your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the PID of the parent process of my application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531837/how-can-i-get-the-pid-of-the-parent-process-of-my-application)

Comment: @HansPassant Not really a duplicate and doesn't answer my issue. I never get rdpinit. I can only get appmenu. myapp should return parent appmenu. appmenu should then return parent rdpinit but it doesn't make it that far in the chain.